# How can I parse out only the last character of a string?

Tags: c++, c, string, parsing, strtok

What I am currently working on is parsing out song titles and artists from an inputted mp3 string.

The string would be in the format of "artist-title.mp3", our teacher provided this information to us and ensured that there will be no `-` characters in any of the songnames, but there may or may not be a `.` character in the title.

The way I have it written right now works perfectly with the `strtok()` function by grabbing only what is before these characters and putting them into the title/artist fields.

Like so:

```
//Parse out the artist and title from the song
    char* artistName = strtok(song, "-");
    char* songName = strtok(NULL, ".");

    //Allocate a new block of memory to the blocks songInfo fields with the correct size
    newBlock->songInfo.artist = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(artistName) + kNullTerminator);
    newBlock->songInfo.title = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(songName) + kNullTerminator);
```

The only problem is if there is a dot in the title name, it will not recognize the full string as the title, it will cut it off. What I want to know is how I can get the last `.` using `strtok()` rather than just the first dot that it finds?

Comment: is it C or C++?

Comment: If C++ `std::string::find_last_of()`

Comment: C++ -> `std::string`. C **or** C++?

Comment: Apparent usage of `malloc()` points this maybe likely related to C.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You are quite an optimist aren't you? **;-)** Maybe questions which don't state the language where relevant should be closed as "too broad".

Comment: @Olaf Well, sir, if that is of any help to OP, then I am, for sure. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh, Sir: The cast tells different (with the same significance ...)

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. Pick the one you actually compile as! One of the differences is that while in C++ you have to cast `void *` (which is e.g. returend my `malloc` & friends), in C you should not.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a while loop, take a look at this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can make use of the [`strrchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr) to find out the last occurrence of the `.` in the input.

That said, using `strtok()`, you can also get this done. Just keep on parsing the same string, until you get NULL and then, consider the last but once case.

Comment: strrchr is the way to go. strtok will destroy the title by setting the dots to zero-bytes, I think, which does not seem to be what the author wants

Comment: Noted, but that just means it would be up to the OP to put the pieces (individual `strtok` returns) together in the event he did have a mid-title `'.'`.

Answer (score 0):

You may actually be making things a bit harder than they need to be by using `strtok`. If your teacher is telling you that the string format is `artist-title.mp3` and is guaranteeing that there will only be one `'-'` in the string (that being the separator), then you already have all the information you need to parse the string into *artist* and *title* without `strtok`.

Think about it. All you need do is read each line. You will first want to confirm that the line ends with `.mp3` and that the line is at least `8` chars long (if read using *line-oriented* input functions like `fgets` or `getline`). Why?

```
 a - a . m p 3 \n
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

If the line is less than `8` chars you cannot have an *artist*, a separator, a *title* and *.mp3* (with trailing newline). You can get the length with a simple call to `strlen`. You can confirm the last 4-chars of the string are `.mp3` with a simple call to `strncmp` beginning at `line[len-5]`.

You next want to confirm that the line contains a `'-'` separator. A simple call to `strchr` both confirms the presence and returns a pointer to the location of the separator within the line.

Knowing the length of the line and the location of the `'-'` separator, your line is already parsed. All you need to do is to *nul-terminate* the parts of the string at the `'-'` separator and the `'.'` (in `.mp3`) and copy the parts to your storage for `artist` and `title`.

Putting the pieces together in a quick example, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *artist;
    char *title;
} track;

enum { MAXS = 128, MAXC = 256 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    track album[MAXS] = {{NULL}, {NULL}};
    char line[MAXC] = {0};
    size_t i, idx = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) 
    {
        char *p = strchr (line, '-');       /* pointer to '-'    */
        size_t len = strlen (line);         /* length of line    */

        if (!p || len < 8 || strncmp (&line[len-5], ".mp3", 4))
            continue;                       /* skip invalid line */

        *p = 0;                             /* nul-terminate at '-' */
        line[len-5] = 0;                    /* nul-terminate at '.' */

        album[idx].artist = strdup (line);  /* alloc/copy artist */
        album[idx++].title = strdup (p + 1);/* alloc/copy title  */

        if (idx == MAXS) {  /* check index against max songs */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXS songs reached.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    printf ("\nArtists & Titles\n");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf ("\n artist : %s\n title  : %s\n",
                album[i].artist, album[i].title);

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
        free (album[i].artist);
        free (album[i].title);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Sammple Input File**

```
$ cat dat/artist-title.txt
This is a collection of songs artist-title in mp3 format

# favorite artists
SO Superband-Against the String.mp3
# a capella
.30 Caliber Quartet-Songs to Die For.mp3
# duets
Dot.com.duet-Internet Harmony.mp3
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_artist_title dat/artist-title.txt

Artists & Titles

 artist : SO Superband
 title  : Against the String

 artist : .30 Caliber Quartet
 title  : Songs to Die For

 artist : Dot.com.duet
 title  : Internet Harmony
```

There are additional validations you could add to protect against a short-read, or check against upper-case `.MP3`, etc., but for the basic logic, you can't get much simpler than just using the information your were given, the lengths involved and a pointer. Let me know if you have any questions.